# Trying to make consensus client and execution client to connect

Tags: go-ethereum, prysm

So I'm new to this and I installed geth and consensus client Prysm. For Geth I'm first running this command:

`geth console --syncmode "snap" --ws --ws.origins "*" --ws.api eth,net,web3 --authrpc.jwtsecret \path\to\jwt.hex`

Now what I notice in my response is this:

> INFO [06-16|15:49:07.427] WebSocket enabled url=ws://127.0.0.1:8546
>
> INFO [06-16|15:49:07.431] WebSocket enabled url=ws://127.0.0.1:8551

So while I'm running this, I get this as a reponse in between "Looking for peers"

> Post-merge network, but no beacon client seen. Please launch one to
> follow the chain!

So then I run Prysm with this command:

```
prysm.bat beacon-chain --execution-endpoint=http://127.0.0.1:8551 --jwt-secret=C:\Users\Loko\Desktop\ethereumnet\consensus\prysm\jwt.hex --suggested-fee-recipient=0xB4ef527Af8a00fEA9c5Dbb7Fa58560d5F431F2e2 --checkpoint-sync-url=https://checkpointz.pietjepuk.net/ --genesis-beacon-api-url=https://checkpointz.pietjepuk.net/
```

Now it looks like they both synced, cause geth showed alot of:

> Forkchoice requested sync to new head    number=17,492,804
> hash=ed837c..e12c3f finalized=17,492,734

While at the same time my Prysm command line did:

> INFO blockchain: Called new payload with optimistic block
> payloadBlockHash=0x319a458d5f6d slot=6675014
>
> [2023-06-16 16:03:13]  INFO blockchain: Called fork choice updated
> with optimistic block finalizedPayloadBlockHash=0x51f9c1bd24a3
> headPayloadBlockHash=0x319a458d5f6d headSlot=6675014
>
> [2023-06-16 16:03:13]  INFO blockchain: Synced new block
> block=0x2c83553f... epoch=208594 finalizedEpoch=208592
> finalizedRoot=0xc480a108... slot=6675014
>
> [2023-06-16 16:03:13]  INFO blockchain: Finished applying state
> transition attestations=128 payloadHash=0x319a458d5f6d slot=6675014
> syncBitsCount=510 txCount=164Called

Now I read at other questions that if you run: `eth.syncing` and it returns 'false', its done syncing. So I did and it returns false, but when I check: `eth.blockNumber` it returns 0

Now while I was writing this, the Prysm cmd spams alot of:

WARN p2p: Attestation is too old to broadcast, discarding it. Current Slot: 6675029 , Attestation Slot: 6674987

and my Geth cmd is returning:

> [06-16|16:06:56.350] Syncing beacon headers downloaded=4,737,536 left=12,755,069 eta=35m39.925s

and the downloaded number keeps going up and the eta keeps going down and my drive is slowly filling up so it looks like it's still downloading, but why is my `eth.syncing` returning a false? Am I missing something?

Also I have not selected a directory, so where would it be writing it now?